# What's the difference between these two pieces of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I'm currently looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17996834) on Stackoverflow about finding combinations of k elements given an n long string. However while making some changes to it (to learn more about it, adapt it to my needs, and convert it to c), I found some problems.

Taking this piece of code:

```
def comb(sofar, rest, k):
  if k == 0:
    print(sofar)
  else:
    for i in range(len(rest)):
       comb(sofar + rest[i], rest[i+1:], k-1)
```

and adding a variable "n" which is supposed to keep the length of the string:

```
def comb(sofar, rest, n, k):
  if k == 0:
    print(sofar)
  else:
    for i in range(0, n):
       comb(sofar + rest[i], rest[i+1:], n-1, k-1)
```

Technically shouldn't these do the same thing? I'm getting a "string index out of range error" but should len(rest) be the same as "n"?

edit:

comb is called with:

```
comb("", "12345", 3)
```

comb2 is called with:

```
comb("", "12345", 5, 3)
```

Comment: How are you sending `n`? It is not the same by the way. Because value of `n` and the `len(rest)` need not be same.

Comment: why would they not be the same though? each time i call comb, i remove the first letter and so subtract 1 from n accordingly right? and I added how I call the function as an edit

Comment: No the lengths are not matching, just manually try to iterate over the loop and you will find your error. I think it should be `n - i - 1` rather than `n - 1`

Comment: ohhhhh, cause it's rest[i+1:] so it cuts it short but a smaller amount for each iteration through the loop, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! If you put that as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it! Thanks again :P

Comment: You can accept now ;)

Comment: lol sorry, apparently there's a 3 minute waiting period and I got distracted while waiting for it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the problem in your code:

`comb(sofar + rest[i], rest[i+1:], n-1, k-1)`

Your tail recursive call is not correct. You are using `rest[i+1:]` and it's length is not `n - 1` for two reasons. You are not updating `n` and you are not modifying `rest` in place. So length of rest will always be less than `n - 1` for all `i > 0`.

You should replace it by `n - i - 1`.

**NOTE**: The first method is the correct way to do anyways. Minimize your dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You call `comb( ..., rest[i+1:], n-1, ...)` and `rest[i+1:]` can be shorter then `n-1`